# Shell command to close the Windows Picture and Fax Viewer

Tags: windows, shell

I know that the shell command to open the Windows Picture and Fax Viewer and view a picture is

```
rundll32.exe c:\windows\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen, [picture path]
```

But what is the shell command to close the same program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shell command to close it.

You could hunt for the window and send it a WM_CLOSE, or you could display the image in a window of your own making and then you'd have full control. Generally speaking though, using this sort of approach to display an image gives up an awful lot of control.

Comment: Thank you for the answer David. So how would I go about sending the window a WM_CLOSE?

Comment: You'd have to find the window first. FindWindowEx or EnumWindows. But if you could do those, then why would you be resorting to rundll32 to show an image?

Comment: So what would be an alternative way of displaying the picture?

Comment: Show it in a window. What language are you programming in?

Comment: The pictures are ordinarily shown in a VBA UserForm in Excel, but the problem is that it does not work with 32-bit pictures, so I need a workaround for those.

Comment: rundll32 to that shell DLL is going to be a disaster, it's a moving target from one version of Windows to the next. Maybe you need a real programming language.

Comment: That is all I have at my disposal unfortunately.

Comment: I figured out how to send a WM_CLOSE to the window.